# Count array by parse value of array

Tags: php, algorithm, codeigniter, yii

How can We count array element inside array.

```
$course = array(
            array(
                'course_name'=> 'HTML',
                'trainee'=> array(
                                array('trainee_name'=>'Hong Va'),
                                array('trainee_name'=>'Reaksmey SE')
                            )
            ),array(
                'course_name'=> 'Java',
                'trainee'=> array(
                                array('trainee_name'=>'Hong Va'),
                                array('trainee_name'=>'Reaksmey SE'),
                                array('trainee_name'=>'Sok Panha'),
                                array('trainee_name'=>'MAO Vannakpanha')
                            )
              )
);
```

I want the result like this:

HTML (2 trainees)

Java (3 trainees)

Comment: Okay, you want it. That's good! What do you want from us?

Comment: First you try and then you'll get help.

Comment: Hint #1: `foreach` + `count`. This is basically all what you need to solve it.

Comment: @Lazy Developer: if you cannot solve such a trivial task - there is a chance that you need to learn php once again from the scratch. Otherwise instead of coding you will spend more time googling and waiting for answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count an array php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373880/count-an-array-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($course as $c){
    echo $c['course_name']."(".count($c['trainee'])." trainees)";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
$course[0]['trainee'][0]['trainee_name'] // Hong Va
$course[0]['trainee'][1]['trainee_name'] // Reaksmey SE
```

JAVA

```
$course[1]['trainee'][0]['trainee_name'] // Hong Va
$course[1]['trainee'][1]['trainee_name'] // Reaksmey SE
$course[1]['trainee'][2]['trainee_name'] // Sok Panha
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use foreach and count

```
  <?php
       $result = array(); // to handle with data later
       foreach($course as $arr) {
          $result[$arr['course_name']] = count($arr['trainee']);        
          // for output here
          echo $arr['course_name'].' ('.count($arr['trainee']).' trainees)<br>';
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it'll also use the correct plural or singular depending on the number of trainees.

```
foreach ($course as $item)
{
    $count = count($item['trainee']);
    $word = ($count == 1) ? 'trainee' : 'trainees';
    echo $item['course_name'] . " ($count $word)"; 
    echo "<br>";
}
```